# How do I find scrape information between 2 tags?

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to **scrape** information with PHP that has their data like so:

```
<br>1998 - <a href="http://example.com/movie/id/2345">A Night at the Roxburry<a/>
```

I need to get the year that is between the `<br>` and the `<a>` tag. I have gotten the title of the movie by using PHP Simple DOM HTML parser. This was the code that I used to parse the title

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link){
    $title = $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

I tried using:

```
$string = '<br>1998 - <a href="http://example.com/movie/id/2345">A Night at the Roxburry<a/>';
$year = preg_match_all('/<br>(.*)<a>', $string);
```

But it's not finding the year that is in between the `<br>` and the `<a>` tag. Does anyone know what I could possibly do to find the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are using: `$year = preg_match_all('/<br>(.*)<a>', $string);` will find text between `<br>` and `<a>`, but in your example you do not have `<a>` anywhere.  Try looking for text between `<br>` and `<a` like this:

```
$year = preg_match_all ('/<br>([^<]*)<a/', $string);
```

note, that I also changed `.` to `[^<]` to make sure it will stop at the next tag, otherwith it will match strings like this:

```
<br>foo<br><br>1998 - <a href="http://site.com/movie/id/2345">A Night at the Roxburry<a
```

because they start with `<br>` and end with `<a`, but this is probably not what you need, any your year will be like this:

```
foo<br><br>1998 - <a href="http://site.com/movie/id/2345">A Night at the Roxburry
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$subject = '<br>1998 - <a href="http://site.com/movie/id/2345">A Night at the Roxburry<a/>';
$pattern = '/<br>[0-9]{4}/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Note that you can change pattern if year is shown in some other formats. If you want to see everything between two tags you can use `$pattern = '/<br>.*<a/';` or any other appropriate for you.